# std::min - design consideration

Tags: c++, c++14

I need to find the minimum of five `float` values, excluding any zero, and its location in the order.

The amount of data, which is going to use this piece of code is going to huge and needs fast processing. this is going to be in a server, which processes inputs `24*7`. the minimum value must get updated in the DB, eventually.

Which would of the following be faster in terms of memory and time usage, or if there is any other simpler way, do let me know.

1. Specialize `std::max` with `tuple`. have four tuple values
   indicating `<value,location>`.

   example,

   ```
   std::tuple<float,int> f1 (10,1);

   bool less(float x, float y)
   { 
       if (x!=0 && x < y)
           return 0;
       else return 1;
   }

   tuple min (std::initializer_list<tuple> il, bool comp){
        what do I do here for initializer list?
   }

   int main () {  
     out << get<1>(min({f1,f2,f3,f4,f5},less));  
   }
   ```
2. Use `std::min_element` and overload the less operator as above?
   would this not be an overkill using an iterator for `float`?

Comment: *The amount of data, which is going to use this piece of code is going to huge* -- How much is "huge"?  And what do you mean by "huge" when you say you only want the minimum of 5 values?  You want the smallest of the 5 values in a large data set?  If that's the case, you're [XY-ing](http://xyproblem.info/) this problem with your approach.

Comment: sorry, edited my posted again .

Comment: It's still not clear.  Forget about your approach -- are you going to get a lot of data, and you want to know what the smallest 5 values are at any time when you're reading this data (from a file, stream, whatever)?

Comment: What's the result if all values are 0?

Comment: I always get 5 values at  a time, and  the minimum of them.
If all values are 0, i return 0.

Comment: As written, the question is not precise enough to get any meaningful answer.

Comment: If it's only 5 values, why do you believe this requires anything special other than a simple `std::min_element` using a simple array of 5 values?  The confusing part is you mentioning "huge data", but not explaining what this really means.  Where is this data coming from?  A file?  A socket?  Is this multithreaded?  If so, using a queue and producer / consumer type logic?  Etc.  Etc.  If this were the case where you want to always keep the 5 smallest items and the data is "huge", then that is a different thing altogether (which is why you need to clarify).

Comment: *would this not be an overkill using iteratoe for float* -- An iterator for a regular array is a simple pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two simple alternatives are:

```
#include <utility>

std::pair<float, unsigned char> my_min(float *a) {
    float val = a[0];
    unsigned char pos = 0;
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        if (a[i] != 0 && (a[i] < val || val == 0)) {
            val = a[i];
            pos = i;
        }
    }
    return {val, pos};
}

int main() {
    float a[5] = {1, 4, 0.5, 0, 5};

    return my_min(a).second;
}
```

and

```
#include <utility>

std::pair<float, unsigned char> my_min(float *a) {
    float val = a[0];
    unsigned char pos = 0;
    float *end = a + 5;
    for (float *ip = a; ip < end; ++ip) {
        float i = *ip;
        if (i != 0 && (i < val || val == 0)) {
            val = i;
            pos = ip - a;
        }
    }
    return {val, pos};
}

int main() {
    float a[5] = {1, 4, 0.5, 0, 5};

    return my_min(a).second;
}
```